# Question on how to go about creating this if formula

Tags: if-statement, indexing, match, vlookup

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question but I want to create some kind of if statement that will take an "Order Number" from column A2 and then check in another sheet in column A if it can find that order number, if it can't find that order number I would like it to say "Error" but if it can find an order number I would like it to say "OK" I do know how to do if statements but don't know how to go about writing this formula, could anyone be of assistance please?

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A vlookup with an iferror should be a good enough

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C10,$B$2:$B$7,1,0),"ERROR")
```

[image]